# I am unable to publishing a notebooks from Watson Studio to Github

Tags: github, repository, github-actions, watson-studio

I am unable to publish my notebooks to GitHub, I have generated a private token and saved it to my IBM Watson studio. I have also created the master branch on Github but I cannot find the settings tab on my IBM projects window; please see attached screengrabs.[my Watson studio screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x2UJg.png)[Coursera lab screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PzKM4.png)

Answer (score 0):

The "Settings" have been moved under the "Manage" tab in a UI redesign a few months back.